# Требуется удалить заведомо не известное слово (словосочетание) из строки, для использования в txt файла

Tags: delphi, pascal, txt, раздел

Существует txt файл, в котором есть строки, например:

1234567 [TAB] Привет, меня зовут Антон! [TAB] 19,06 [TAB] 600,6

8910112 [TAB] Привет, меня зовут Дима! [TAB] 29,24 [TAB] 500

1314151[TAB] Привет, меня зовут Коля! [TAB] 16,53 [TAB] 234,734

(Текст для примера, к реальным данным не относится!)

И, так, к сути вопроса:

Требуется удалить текст между числами т.е. должно получиться следующее:

1234567 [TAB] 19,06 [TAB] 600,6

8910112 [TAB] 29,24 [TAB] 500

1314151[TAB] 16,53 [TAB] 234,734

И нужно это сделать средствами Delphi. Есть кусок кода, где эти данные уже записаны динамический массив:

```
for index := 11 to Length(massivFromFile)-1 do
            begin

              b := BytesOf(massivFromFile[index]);
              b := TEncoding.Convert(TEncoding.GetEncoding(1251), TEncoding.GetEncoding(866), b);
              Result := StringOf(b);
              Writeln(t, Result);

            end;
```

Кол-во строк, как и словосочетания заведомо не известны, поэтому использовался массив.

Answer (score 0):

Разделите строку по табам, например, с помощью DelimitedText (StrictDelimiter надо учесть)

Проверьте, есть ли в каждой выделенной подстроке буквы (через вхождение во множество символов или с помощью регулярных выражений)

Соберите подходящие строки обратно с помощью того же DelimitedText

Comment: 1. Если структура точно известна (в вопросе "неизвестный" текст всегда на втором месте), то можно не проверять, а просто выкинуть 2-й элемент. 2. Если использовать RegExp, то разделять строку и не обязательно - сразу заменить. Но если правило отсева замысловатое, лучше, думаю, RegExp не использовать - сложнее потом читать и отлаживать будет.

Comment: Я бы пошёл через TStringList, с возможным использованием TRegEx

Comment: @Viktor Tomilov Ну да, DelimitedText подразумевает TStringList, а про регулярки я уже на всякий случай написал.